# Inequality with absolute function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

[image]

The answer is at the bottom. Can anybody explain where I am wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please express this answer using at least plain text, if not MathJax. Simply providing a picture of a sheet of paper is not good practice on this site.

Comment: The transition to the next to last line is incorrect.

Comment: Search for "Math StackExchange LaTeX guide".

Comment: The graph of $f(x) = \mid\sqrt{x}-1\mid$ is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Second and Third line are Right, Then

$\displaystyle $ From $-1<\sqrt{x}-1< \sqrt{2}-1$

(Here we can not multiply each term by $-1$, bcz we have to calculate range of $|\sqrt{x}-1|$)

Now Taking modulus on each term, We get $|-1|<|\sqrt{x}-1|<|\sqrt{2}-1|$

So we get $0\leq |\sqrt{x}-1|<1$

Bcz $\bf{Modulus\; Quantity\geq 0}$ and in $1$ and $\sqrt{2}-1\approx 0.41$

So here $1$ is greater then $\sqrt{2}-1$

Comment: Thanks, why can't sqrt(2)-1 be there instead of 1?

Comment: bcz $\max\left\{1,\sqrt{2}-1\right\} = 1$. So we will take $1$ as a upper bond

Comment: Oh, so for this kind of inequality, when we take modulus on both sides, we need to compare both the values on either side and use the bigger one as the upper bound? then the lower bound would always be 0?

Comment: Yes you are Right, and for lower bond $\bf{modulus\; quantity\geq 0}$ bcz minimum of modulus is $=0$

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

$$-1 < \sqrt{x}-1 < \sqrt{2}-1$$
$$|-1| < |\sqrt{x}-1| < |\sqrt{2}-1|$$
$$1 < |\sqrt{x}-1| < \sqrt{2}-1$$
Since $\sqrt{2}-1 < 1$ and $0 < 1$, we can write the inequality as such:
$$0 < 1 < |\sqrt{x}-1| < \sqrt{2}-1 < 1$$
Or simply
$$0 < |\sqrt{x}-1| < 1$$

Comment: Thanks, why can't sqrt(2)-1 be there instead of 1?

Comment: @user271948 $\sqrt{2}-1$ is actually a tighter bound than $1$, and so it is perfectly fine to leave it that way. However, since you had the answer desired you can simply loosen the bounds to transform your equation to the provided solution. This is especially useful if you are using integer values of $x$, as having irrational bounds is less useful in this case.